# Remove second shutter button from S10e camera app

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-s-10

The stock camera app on my rooted Sampung S10e is working fine, but since a few days there is a second shutter:

[image]

I can move it, but it is useless and troublesome wherever I put it.

How to remove it? I only need the default shutter button.

Comment: is the position of the second shutter button fixed or does it move? It it is the latter it may may mark the focus point. Or it is simply a bug.

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with Accessibility feature, but I can't test my hypothesis since I don't have Samsung devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Touch the second shutter and hold it
2. Move it on top of the original shutter
3. Release it
4. The second shutter disappears

You can check that it really disappears by putting it a few pixels besides the original shutter, and see it disappear.

If you ever want this second shutter again, just hold then move the original shutter, it will create the secondary shutter. You can dispose of it again the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If it was not there before, You can try clearing app data of camera.
Long press Camera app -> App Info -> Storage -> Clear Storage

Comment: I just tried, it works, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help, you may mark this answer as accepted. :)

Comment: The other answer has the advantage of not resetting all of your camera settings, though :-)

Comment: That's Better then.